# How to get the Version Number for JBoss 7 from within a WAR?

Tags: jboss, version, jmx, war

For older JBoss these mechanisms worked :

- Check for Class `org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanServerLocator`
- Then use JSR77: Look for a JMX MBean with `*:j2eeType=J2EEServer,*` and get the attribute `serverVersion`

or

- Check for an MBean with name `jboss.system:type=Server` and get the value of attribute `Version`

But for JBoss 7 neither MBean exists (nor any suitable class to check, with the WAR sitting in its OSGi cage). All I can do is for searching the JMX domain `jboss.modules:` if it exists infer that this is a Jboss 7.

Is there a way to get the exact version number from within a WAR's init() ?